# Работа с List, IList не сохраняет 1-й результат

Tags: c#, list, классы

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Stat_Update.Classes
{   //Класс пораметров
    public class UnParam
    {
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string lastver { get; set; }
        public string size { get; set; }
        public string needRestart { get; set; }
    }
    //Класс процедуры
    public partial class UnUpdate
    {
        #region - Объявляем переменные
        public UnParam UnParam { get; set; }
        #endregion
        //Запуск модуля проверки обновления
    public static IList<List<UnParam>> UpdateXml(string docLocale, string docServer)
    {
        List<List<UnParam>> par3 = new List<List<UnParam>>();
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            List<UnParam> parLocal = new List<UnParam>();
            List<UnParam> parGlobal = new List<UnParam>();
            try
            {
                //читаем данные из файла
                XDocument docLoc = XDocument.Load(docLocale);
                //проходим по каждому элементу в найшей library
                foreach (XElement el in docLoc.Root.Elements())
                {
                    UnParam unParam = new UnParam
                    {
                        path = el.Attribute("path").Value,
                        url = el.Attribute("url").Value,
                        lastver = el.Attribute("lastver").Value,
                        size = el.Attribute("size").Value,
                        needRestart = el.Attribute("needRestart").Value 
                    };
                    parLocal.Add(unParam);
                }
                par3.Add(parLocal);
                XDocument docSer = XDocument.Load(docServer);
                foreach (XElement el in docSer.Root.Elements())
                {
                    UnParam unParam = new UnParam
                    {
                        path = el.Attribute("path").Value,
                        url = el.Attribute("url").Value,
                        lastver = el.Attribute("lastver").Value,
                        size = el.Attribute("size").Value,
                        needRestart = el.Attribute("needRestart").Value
                    };
                    parGlobal.Add(unParam);
                }
                par3.Add(parGlobal);
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return par3;
    }
    //Запуск модуля скачивания обновления
    public static void Execute(IList<UnParam> unParamLocal, IList<UnParam> unParamServer)
    {
    }
    //Запуск обновления
    static void Update(UnParam requestParameters)
    {
    }
  }
}
*********Сам проект в нём объявляем*******  
public static IList<UnParam> Local = new List<UnParam>();
public static IList<UnParam> Global = new List<UnParam>();
*********Код допустим кнопки*********
//Это фиксированная ссылка на локальный файл обновления
string LocalIn = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + Properties.Settings.Default.LoadIn;
//Это фиксированная ссылка на глобальный файл обновления
string GlobalOut = Properties.Settings.Default.LoadOut;
//Парсим файлы
Global = UnUpdate.UpdateXml(LocalIn, GlobalOut);
//UnUpdate.Execute(LocalIn, GlobalOut);
```

**ТО ИСХОДЯ ИЗ КОДА:** 
*Теперь оба xml файла, парсятся за один присест, и передаются обратно вложенными в "List", но мне кажется что такая конструкция громоздка. Хотя то что я хотел вроде достигнуто т.е. В одном **List** есть 2 вложенных первый это локальный **xml** а второй удалённый **xml**. этого я и добивался.

**Теперь про оптимизацию!
Жду вариантов?!***

Answer (score 3):

- В вашем методе вы **два раза** делаете одно и то же. Вынесите общий код и сделайте что-нибудь в таком духе:

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<UnParam> ParseXmlContents(string uri)
  {
      XDocument document = XDocument.Load(uri);

      foreach (XElement element in document.Root.Elements)
      {
          yield return new UnParam
          {
              path = element.Attribute("path").Value,
              url = element.Attribute("url").Value,
              lastver = element.Attribute("lastver").Value,
              size = element.Attribute("size").Value,
              needRestart = element.Attribute("needRestart").Value
          };
      }
  }

  // Вызывающая сторона:
  IEnumerable<UnParam> localXmlContents = ParseXmlContents(localIn);
  IEnumerable<UnParam> globalXmlContents = ParseXmlContents(globalIn);
  ```
- Можете также ввести фабричный метод с семантикой `'UnParam FromXmlElement(XElement element);'` и использовать его для создания объектов `UnParam.`

Comment: Спасибо, сразу в голову не пришло вынести отдельно. Хорошее решение.

Comment: я бы foreach + yield return переписал как Select

Comment: @VladD Да, можно, разве что это уж совсем кардинально будет отличаться от исходного варианта автора.

Comment: @Котик: надо приучать людей к элементам ФП :)

Comment: @VladD

Что-то я не уверен, что для случая `par3.Add(parGlobal)` и `catch {}` знание куска `ФП` в виде `LINQ` сильно исправит ситуацию :)

Comment: @Котик: путь в тысячу ли начинается с первого шага (если не наврал с китайской единицей длины).

Answer (score 0):

Уберите `public static List<UnParam> par = new List<UnParam>();` из класса `UnUpdate`. Вместо этого статического поля (которое вы перезатираете при каждом вызове UpdateXml) исрользуйте локальную переменную в методе UpdateXml.

Comment: Теперь оба xml файла, парсятся за один присест, и передаются обратно вложенными в "List", но мне кажется что такая конструкция громоздка. Хотя то что я хотел вроде достигнуто т.е. В одном List есть 2 вложенных первый это локальный xml а второй удалённый xml. этого я и добивался.
Теперь про оптимизацию! Жду вариантов?!